# Add Kendo ComoBox editor to NopCommerce

Tags: kendo-ui, nopcommerce, kendo-combobox

How I can create an editor template for kendo ComboBox in NopCommerce
I tried this snippet but when open the page the returns as html text

//Editor

```
<input id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)"  />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)").kendoComboBox({
                        placeholder: "Select",
                        dataTextField: '@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["dataTextField"]',
                        dataValueField: "@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["dataValueField"]",
                        filter: "contains",
                        autoBind: false,
                        minLength: 3,
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: '@Html.Action(ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["ActionName"].ToString(), ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Controller"].ToString())',
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

//In View

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```

//View Model

```
[UIHint("ComboBox")]
[AdditionalMetadata("dataTextField","FirstName")]
[AdditionalMetadata("dataValueField","Id")]
[AdditionalMetadata("ActionName","MyActionName")]
[AdditionalMetadata("Controller","MyController")]
public int MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Can anyone help me with this case please

Comment: refer this link : http://www.nop-templates.com/blog/tag/nopCommerce%20tutorials